# Reliable, Free Flight Alert Website allowing multiple route combinations

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

Does anybody know of a website that gives reliable flight alerts for low fares?

Ideally, I would like it to :

1. Be free
2. Allow alerts on routes (ex. MXP - TXL), or from city to city (Milan - Berlin). If by city it is not possible, then allow multiple routes, so I can check all combinations of departure and arrival airports
3. Compare all (or at least most) airline companies
4. Send e-mails weekly
5. Include return flights

Am I asking too much?

**EDIT**: With [Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.net/) I think I can set alerts for a specific day, but I want to see when flights to a specific destination are at the cheapest, *when* does not matter.

Comment: Alerts for what? Low fares?

Comment: @Relaxed yes, I edited my question.

Comment: Ack, you've changed. "I want to see when flights ...when does not matter". do you mean "where"?

Comment: @MarkMayo I mean, I want to find which day(s) a flight is at its cheapest, any day and not just a date I specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many sites, including Skyscanner, Kayak, Hipmunk or Momondo can watch flights on a specific date for you, often also for several airports at once. But you cannot get a weekly report about arbitrary return flights between two destinations at any date in the future. As Mark already explained, Kayak can however warn you about cheap weekend deals (using “upcoming weekends” as the time frame).

[Adioso](http://adioso.com/) is somewhat more flexible than most. It lets you set up searches for things like return flights between two countries or cities (not airports) at anytime in the future for a trip lasting about two weeks and then set up an alarm. I don't know how reliable it is (the more flexible, the more likely it is to miss something) and you cannot get weekly emails (you have to specify a threshold and get an email whenever a flight cheaper than your threshold becomes available).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I tried it, and you can set the "anytime" option. It is not exactly what I am looking for, but with a bit of manual work it does what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Kayak.com allows you to create price alerts.  So let's run through your criteria.

1. Free - it is, yes.  Well, you have to sign up so you're giving them some information.
2. Sure, it's not just 'ex-NZ specials, but city specific, or multiple.  For example, you can have a search:

   [Flights from SYD to CHC on a specific day, one-way)(https://www.kayak.com.au/flights/SYD-CHC/2015-03-27)

   or something more complex:

   [Flights from SYD, or either Melbourne airport, to either Christchurch or Auckland, return, business class, on this specific date, but I'm flexible by +/-3 days on the return](https://www.kayak.com.au/flights/SYD,MEL,AVV-CHC,AKL/2015-03-27/2015-04-15-flexible/business)
3. Well it checks most that I care about. I know RyanAir in Europe isn't on it, but it covers most you'd want to fly with.
4. Weekly? You can choose daily or weekly (a [tutorial on creating one has a screenshot of this if you want evidence](http://www.milevalue.com/how-to-set-a-kayak-price-alert-an-easy-way-to-save-hundreds/)

   Kayak's [sample page showing what your alerts look like, aside from the emails](https://www.kayak.com.au/images/sample-alerts.png)
5. Well, as shown above you can specify return or one-way flights.  And it doesn't even have to be to the same place - you can do a search from/to multiple airports, eg, I used to search BNE,SYD,MEL to YVR,PDX,SEA when I was looking for cheap flights last year from Australia to the Pacific North West.

Are you asking too much? Nope. It's a great tool and probably underused by most, myself included. This has reminded me I should set up more on it.

Comment: I think the OP does not want to watch a specific date but just find cheap flights in the future. I think Kayak allows “upcoming weekends” as date, maybe that's something to add to your answer. Unfortunately, it does not seem possible to set up an alert for longer stays or one-way flights without a date (or at least a six-day period) in mind.

Comment: He's edited it post , and damn it's frustrating when you address a long itemised question and they change it :/
If it's just that, we actually have other questions covering 'upcoming cheap flights' etc.  Stats on when is the cheapest is unlikely.  I may edit it tomorrow though after some thought.

Comment: Sorry, I write questions fast and then edit them based on the feedback that I get and the clarity. I'll try not to do it anymore.